# Tracing Sequelize with AWS X-ray in Nodejs/Postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-xray

I am using Serverless NodeJs with PostgreSQL and want to start tracing Sequelize queries with AWS X-ray. The documentation only shows how we can trace the pg clients but doesn't state how we can do the same for Sequelize ORM. Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is answered [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-node/issues/271) on our github repo. The X-Ray Node SDK doesn't currently support tracing of sequelize queries. We have added it to our backlog. Please stay tuned.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This only capture db calls. This is how you can do it. dialect need to be specific

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const AWSXRay = require('aws-xray-sdk');
AWSXRay.captureHTTPsGlobal(require('https'));

const sequelize = () => {
    return new Sequelize(database, username, password, {
        host: host,
        dialect: 'mysql',
        dialectModule: AWSXRay.captureMySQL(require('mysql2')),
    });
};
```

Comment: Is it this working solutions?